# Getting the second value of an attribute in XML using php

Tags: php, xml, xpath

How do I only get the seconde value of the attribute "Role"(In this case "Student")?

```
<saml:Attribute Name="Role">
  <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">Master</saml:AttributeValue>
  <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">Student</saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enhanced a bit your sample xml and loaded it into a string so you can see the effect of the xpath expression being applied. Also notice that you need to register all the namespaces used in the xml file. The prefixes doesn't need to match the xml but the registered prefixes are the ones you need to use on your xpath expression.

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<root xmlns:saml="http://example.org" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<saml:Attribute Name="Role">
  <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">Master</saml:AttributeValue>
  <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">Student1</saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
<saml:Attribute Name="Unknown">
  <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">Zero</saml:AttributeValue>
  <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">One</saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
<saml:Attribute Name="Role">
  <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">Master</saml:AttributeValue>
  <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">Student2</saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
</root>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('a','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('b','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('s','http://example.org');

$result = $xml->xpath('//s:Attribute[@Name="Role"]/s:AttributeValue[2]');

foreach ($result as $a)
{
print $a . "\n";
}

?>
```